# Getting data's from json_url and how to insert to my mysql database

Tags: php, arrays, json

here is json data im getting from *$api_url*

i want insert those data to my  mysql db, what should have to do after getting json data?

i tried some tutorials but not working ,im not getting flow

help me.

```
Array
([match_id] => 41962
    [title] => Australia Women vs India Women
    [competition] => Array
        ([title] => ICC Women's T20 World Cup
            [abbr] => iwtwc-201920
            [type] => tournament
            [category] => international
            [match_format] => woment20)
[teama] => Array
        ( [team_id] => 8652
            [name] => Australia Women
            [short_name] => AUS-W
            [logo_url] => https://cricket.entitysport.com/assets/uploads/2016/03/australia-women.png
            [scores_full] => 184/4 (20 ov)  )
    [teamb] => Array
        ( [team_id] => 9536
            [name] => India Women
            [short_name] => IND-W
            [logo_url] => https://cricket.entitysport.com/assets/uploads/2016/03/india-women.png
            [scores_full] => *99/10 (19.1 ov)
    [date_start] => 2020-03-08 07:00:00
    [date_end] => 2020-03-08 19:00:00
    [venue] => Array
        ( [venue_id] => 111
            [name] => Melbourne Cricket Ground
            [location] => Melbourne)
    [umpires] => Ahsan Raza (Pakistan), Kim Cotton (New Zealand), Gregory Brathwaite (West Indies, TV)
    [referee] => Chris Broad (England)
    [toss] => Array
        ( [text] => Australia Women won the toss & elected to bat
            [winner] => 8652
            [decision] => 1))
Array
(" " second data's)
to be continue ...
```

i just getting json data here
**mtach.php**

```
$api_url='https://rest.entitysport.com/v2/matches/?status=2&token=ec471071441bb2ac538a0ff901abd249';

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$api_url);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $cricketMatches= json_decode(json_encode(json_decode($result)), True);
            
           foreach($cricketMatches as $matchs) { 
            foreach ($matchs as $items) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($item);
//code for insert data to mysql.
            }
            }
           }
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Did you define your table structure ?

Comment: here is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hrzDGX8sXbE5wltfFtoFiyF4Nqr657fy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you need to store all the data (ex: team name) you should have a table per entity. Ex: team, competition, venue ... with the foreign keys well defined. 
And then insert the data with mysqli_query(your_query)

What is the actual problem ? Where are you getting stuck ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```php
<?php

$api_url = 'https://rest.entitysport.com/v2/matches/?status=2&token=ec471071441bb2ac538a0ff901abd249';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result_json = json_decode(json_encode(json_decode($result)), True);
$data = $result_json["response"];

// setup PDO connection 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cricket', 'root', '');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO `cricket`
                (match_id, competition_id, toss_winner_team, winner_team, teamid1, teamid2, match_status, matchStarted,
                type, time, match_date_time, title, team1Score, team1Over, team2Score, team2Over, match_status_note)
        VALUES
                (:match_id, :competition_id, :toss_winner_team, :winner_team, :teamid1, :teamid2, :match_status, :matchStarted,
                :type, :time, :match_date_time, :title, :team1Score, :team1Over, :team2Score, :team2Over, :match_status_note)
        "
);
try {
        $pdo->beginTransaction();
        foreach ($data["items"] as $key => $value) {
                $stmt->bindParam(':match_id', $value['match_id']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':competition_id', $value['competition']['cid']); 

                $stmt->bindParam(':toss_winner_team', $value['toss']['text']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':winner_team', $value['winning_team_id']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':teamid1', $value['teama']['team_id']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':teamid2', $value['teamb']['team_id']); 

                $stmt->bindParam(':match_status', $value['status_str']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':matchStarted', $value['date_start']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':type', $value['competition']['type']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':time', $value['timestamp_start']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':match_date_time', $value['date_end']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':title', $value['title']); 

                $stmt->bindParam(':team1Score', $value['teama']['scores_full']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':team1Over', $value['teama']['overs']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':team2Score', $value['teamb']['scores_full']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':team2Over', $value['teamb']['overs']); 

                $stmt->bindParam(':match_status_note', $value['status_note']); 

                $stmt->execute();

                // echo "Inserted {$key} item..<br>";
        }
        $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo->rollback();
        throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..getting error         Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\im1\index.php on line 16
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\im1\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\im1\index.php on line 16

Comment: I wrote $db instead of $pdo. Updated it now. Should work.

Comment: yes i got it . its work thanks. one more if want update table data every second what should i have to do?

Comment: Why would you need to update the data every second? It defeats the purpose of API itself. If you want to consume the latest data in your application, just call the API from the application itself. Anyways, if you still want to refresh the data every second, set up a cron job on your hosting server which will execute the script after set interval. If you don't have access to cron jobs, you can wrap this code in a function and then call it in a while(true) loop with sleep(1000) inside the loop.

Comment: one more thing, if i have save team data to another table what can i do changes in code,